# Catchfilebetweentags not working

Tags: catchfile

According to the description of `catchfilebetweentags` package command `\ExecuteMetaData*[<file>]{tag}` should do the same job as `\ExecuteMetaData[<file>]{tag}` but also ,,uncomment'' comment lines with single `%` at the beginning. File:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{catchfilebetweentags}
\begin{document}
\ExecuteMetaData*[example.tex]{tag}
\end{document}
```

with the following file example.tex:

```
%<*tag>
some text 
%some more text
%</tag>
```

should produce output:

some text some more text

Unfortunately, in Texmaker it gives:

[example.tex]tag

while in Overleaf it compiles for 30 seconds and timeout error pops up. How can this be fixed?

Comment: Where I can take your [example.tex]tag?

Comment: @Sebastiano, [example.tex]tag is precisely the output (one line with 16 characters - 13 letters, a full stop and square brackets). Is this what you mean in your question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry, but there's no solution. Consider the example

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname-example}
%<*tag>
some text 
%some more text
%</tag>

\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{catchfilebetweentags}

\begin{document}

\tracingmacros=1 % for debugging

\CatchFileBetweenTags{\foo}{\jobname-example.tex}{tag}\show\foo

\CatchFileBetweenTags*{\foo}{\jobname-example.tex}{tag}

%\ExecuteMetaData[\jobname-example.tex]{tag}

\end{document}
```

The first `\CatchFileBetweenTags` starts with

```
\CatchFileBetweenTags #1#2#3->\CatchFileBetweenDelims \CatchFBT@tok {#2}{%<*#3>}{%</#3>}[\CatchFBT@sanitize ]\CatchFBT@Final {#1}
#1<-\foo 
#2<-\jobname -example.tex
#3<-tag
```

whereas the second one has

```
\CatchFileBetweenTags #1#2#3->\CatchFileBetweenDelims \CatchFBT@tok {#2}{%<*#3>}{%</#3>}[\CatchFBT@sanitize ]\CatchFBT@Final {#1}
#1<-*
#2<-\foo 
#3<-\jobname -example.tex
```

and you can clearly see that something is wrong.

Worse: the definition of `\ExecuteMetaData` is

```
% catchfilebetweentags.sty, line 53:
\newrobustcmd*\ExecuteMetaData[2][\jobname]{%
   \CatchFileBetweenTags\CatchFBT@tok{#1}{#2}%
   \global\expandafter\CatchFBT@tok\expandafter{%
            \expandafter}\the\CatchFBT@tok
}% \ExecuteMetaData
```

so there is ***no provision at all*** for distinguishing between `\ExecuteMetaData` and `\ExecuteMetaData*`.

Apparently the author documented his wishes about the package, but forgot to implement them.

Comment: Is there any way to achieve the desired result (catchfile which "uncomments" lines)? Shall I ask another question on the forum?

Comment: @Tomasz23 Maybe a real use case would help.